# Xcode error : Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in Swift (game application)

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, sprite-kit

I created a new OS X game project with Spritekit in swift, but when I try to run the initial code (without modifying anything) I keep getting error in the title at the first line :

```
 class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
```

Assertion failed: (*shader), function xglCompileShader, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Jet/Jet-1.50/Jet/xgl_utils.mm, line 24.

I tried to google the error the I can't find anything on this. :(

Also I don't have a mac so I'm using a VM, dunno if it changes anything. :/